# Oracle SQL. How to select specific IDs where value of columns specify criteria?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the following statement/query:

```
SELECT table1.file_id,
   table1.status,
   table2.status
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.file_id = table2.file_id;
```

The result is as follows:

```
   FILE ID   |   Status Table 1    |   Status Table 2
-----------------------------------------------------
   5500002   |        AX           |        ICS
   5500002   |        AX           |        ICSO
   5500002   |        AXO          |        ICS
   5500003   |        AX           |        ICS
   5500003   |        AX           |        ICS
   5500003   |        AX           |        ICS
   5500004   |        NULL         |        ICSO test
   5500004   |        AXO          |        ICS
   5500004   |        AX           |        NULL
```

I need for each File ID to check for four statuses:

```
 - AX
 - AXO
 - ICS
 - ICSO
```

I now only want to run a select on the `File ID`s that cover all four statuses. As you can see the `File ID` occurs multiple times and I'd want for my query to return only the `File ID` that fulfills the requirement, which in this instance would return 5500002 and 5500004.

For 5500004, there is a status that mentions `ICSO test` but regardless of the remainder of the text if it were to contain ICSO within the cell, it counts as ICSO. Same applies to other statuses.

How would I go about adding to the query to SELECT only the specific IDs?

Comment: you need to select only those file ids, which have all 4 statuses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like below

```
SELECT file_id
FROM
(
SELECT table1.file_id,
   table1.status as status1,
   table2.status as status2
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.file_id = table2.file_id
) tab
GROUP BY file_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tab.status1) + COUNT(DISTINCT tab.status2) >= 4
```

Comment: How would I have access to status1 and status2 outside the subquery? Do I need to initialize outside somehow?

Comment: NO, you will have access to those column since you are actually running the outer query against that inline view (inner query result)

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways to do this.

The most straightforward method to me is like this:

```
SELECT t1.file_id,
   t1.status,
   t2.status
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.file_id = t2.file_id
WHERE t1.file_id IN (SELECT file_id FROM table1 WHERE status = 'AX')
    AND t1.file_id IN (SELECT file_id FROM table1 WHERE status = 'AXO')
    AND t1.file_id IN (SELECT file_id FROM table2 WHERE status = 'ICS')
    AND t1.file_id IN (SELECT file_id FROM table2 WHERE status LIKE '%ICSO%');
```

You can also do it like this:

```
SELECT t1.file_id,
   t1.status,
   t2.status
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.file_id = t2.file_id
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE status = 'AX' AND file_id = t1.file_id)
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE status = 'AXO' AND file_id = t1.file_id)
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 WHERE status = 'ICS' AND file_id = t1.file_id)
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 WHERE status LIKE '%ICSO%' AND file_id = t1.file_id);
```

Or even like this:

```
SELECT t1.file_id,
   t1.status,
   t2.status
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.file_id = t2.file_id
WHERE t1.file_id IN (
    SELECT file_id FROM table1 WHERE status = 'AX'
    INTERSECT
    SELECT file_id FROM table1 WHERE status = 'AXO'
    INTERSECT
    SELECT file_id FROM table2 WHERE status = 'ICS'
    INTERSECT
    SELECT file_id FROM table2 WHERE status LIKE '%ICSO%');
```

But INTERSECT isn't always the best performing option due to the implicit DISTINCT.

You'll have to try them out to see which one performs the best for you.